# Positioning cursor using eye movement

Tags: mouse, gui, camera, accessibility

I'm interested in replacing my mouse with a camera and software to automatically place the cursor under point on the screen I'm looking at. Where could I find something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Most of this technology is still under development, but you can try [PCBility](http://www.pcbility.com/) which has a demo and just uses a regular webcam.  This seems to use your face and not just your eyes.